# Query for last measurement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already fight many days for a SQL query to get the latest entry of a table.
It's about measurements. So you have table 1 (`S_QOS_DATA`) for your profiles and table 2 (`RN_QOS_DATA`) for the messure results.
Now I want a query to get from every Profile the latest measurement with its value.

I already tried many things.

The function `last()` isn't available in MS SQL so I have to use `last_value` and I have many problems with it.

```
SELECT rn.table_id, d.robot, d.target, max(rn.sampletime) as "Letzte Messung",
       last_value(rn.sampletime) over (PARTITION by rn.table_id order by rn.sampletime DESC )
FROM RN_QOS_DATA_0012 as rn,
     S_QOS_DATA as d  
WHERE d.table_id = rn.table_id    
  AND target not LIKE 'QS_%'  
  AND target not LIKE 'TEST_%'  
  AND target not LIKE 'ENTW_%'   
  AND target not LIKE '%Ctrl%' 
  AND target not LIKE '%Arbeitsplatzaufbau%'   
  AND target not LIKE 'RT_%' 
  --and rn.samplevalue is not NULL 
  AND target LIKE '%gesamt%' 
group by d.robot, d.target, rn.table_id, rn.sampletime
order by max(rn.sampletime)
```

Could someone help me please?!

S_QOS_DATA:
table_id    4   int identity
ci_metric_id    12  varchar
qos_def_id  4   int
created 93  smalldatetime
checksum    12  varchar
qos 12  varchar
source  12  nvarchar
target  12  nvarchar
host    12  nvarchar
origin  12  nvarchar
robot   12  nvarchar
probe   12  varchar
r_table 12  varchar
h_table 12  varchar
v_table 12  varchar
sampletime  93  datetime
samplevalue 2   numeric
samplemax   2   numeric
nim_origin  12  nvarchar
modifier    12  varchar
samplerate  2   numeric

RN_QOS_DATA_0012:
table_id    4   int
sampletime  93  datetime
samplevalue 2   numeric
samplestdev 2   numeric
samplerate  2   numeric
tz_offset   4   int

Comment: Please provide some sample data in the form `declare @RN_QOS_DATA_0012 table
(
Column1 int primary key not null,
Column2 nvarchar(10),
ColumnX datetime2 not null ....
)` and then `insert into @RN_QOS_DATA_0012
        (Column1, Column2, ColumnX)
values  (0...`

Comment: To get an accurate answer you will need to provide the schema for the two tables, sample data of what is in those tables, and an example of what you expect to get from the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    rn.table_id, 
    d.robot, 
    d.target, 
    rn.sampletime,
    rank() over (PARTITION by rn.table_id order by rn.sampletime DESC ) rownum,
    rn.samplevalue
  FROM RN_QOS_DATA_0012 as rn,
  JOIN
       S_QOS_DATA as d  
  ON
       d.table_id = rn.table_id    
  WHERE 
    target not LIKE 'QS_%'  
    AND target not LIKE 'TEST_%'  
    AND target not LIKE 'ENTW_%'   
    AND target not LIKE '%Ctrl%' 
    AND target not LIKE '%Arbeitsplatzaufbau%'   
    AND target not LIKE 'RT_%' 
    AND target LIKE '%gesamt%' 
)
SELECT 
  table_id, 
  robot, 
  target, 
  sampletime,
  samplevalue
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1
GROUP BY
  robot, target, table_id, sampletime, samplevalue
ORDER BY
  sampletime
```

Comment: First of all thank you.
I tried it but still need the colume samplevalue in the query.

Comment: @Jessi ok, that wasn't very clear from the question. It has been included now

Answer (score 0):

Generally this can not be done in one query - you need 2 queires. FIrst to identify the most accurate sample time, then join that with the data.

Now, you can do those 2 queries in one sql statement, because you can actually have a SELECT clause instead of a table name.

SELECT * FROM A, (SELECT....) as B

is valid.

A tutorial can be found at http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

So, the inner query determines the most accurate sample time grouped by the other fields needed, then the outer query joins the relevant other data.